# Why is view code not wrapped inside classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, class, model-view-controller

This is one of these "Why do things work in a certain way" questions.

Since Rails is a purely object oriented language, controller code, model code, helper code, migration code, etc. is wrapped inside classes. But not view code.

So I was wondering: how does Rails know that view code belongs to the [Active View class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html)? How does that work internally?

Comment: Take a look at the render call in the Rails code. There is a Railscasts walk-through of ActionView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Ruby files run inside of a class, just run a file that contains this:

```
puts self.class.name
```

and you'll see that your code is wrapped in an `Object` class when it executes.

Comment: Thanks for that - strangely, `self.class?`
 puts a class, but `self.class.name` puts nothing. How come?

Comment: `puts self.class.name` prints `Object` for me. Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Doesn't put anything for me - same ruby version here

Comment: Regardless, while my answer isn't terribly informative all ruby code is executed in the context of a class, and I'm sure that rails will execute views in the context of a class as well.

Comment: I am aware if that - but then why don't we as programmers have to wrap our view code inside a class?

Comment: @Charles What I'm trying to say is that if you wrap it or not, it's in a class. Your asking why you don't have to manually wrap it in a class? Possibly because it's parsed by ERB or HAML or some other templating engine. But again, whether you wrap it or not, it's a class. So if it was required to be part of a class, you've made it in a class just by writing the file. It also executes with the context of your controller as a class so I would imagine that the controller is the actual "class" of your view. Try doing `self.class.name` in a view and see what you get.